# Hardware used for render

Tags: hardware

I have some issues with renderings
My CPU and GPU date from '11. 
Can someone give me some specs that will do the job quick and with high quality?

Hope i did not bothered you with my question and am lookng forward to  your advice
Hope to hear from you .

Kind regards